# Query column by Array value in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to query a table by an array which I fetch from the same table and the selected column also be an array with respect to the conditional array. Data example:

```
component   description     con_1   con_2   flag
    A       product_1       211     311     1
    A       product_2       212     null    0
    A       product_3       213     null    1
    B       product_4       null    322     2
    B       product_1       null    323     2
    C       product_6       null    341     2
    C       product_7       null    341     2
```

In the above table, firstly make an array of con_1 and con_2 based on the flag.
Following is the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT component,
    ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN flg = 1 THEN con_1 WHEN flg = 2 THEN con_2 ELSE NULL END con FROM product_table WHERE component = p.component AND flg <> 0) AS con
FROM product_table p
```

Here is the output for this query:

```
component           con
    A               {211, 213}
    B               {322, 323}
    C               {341}
```

Now here is the problem. I need to fetch the array of [description] column by the array value of [con].
But if any [con] value contains multiple [description] then only one [description] value need to fetch.

For example, on the [product_table] there have two [description] of {341}, that is {product_6, product_7}. But I need to fetch any one value like {product_6} or {product_7}. So, the main expected table is:

```
component       description                     con
    A           {product_1, product_3}          {211, 213}
    B           {product_4, product_1}          {322, 323}
    C           {product_6}                     {341}
```

This is an example data. Sorry for any inconvenience as I unable to extract data out. Btw, appreciating for any helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with cte as (
SELECT DISTINCT on (1,2) component,
    CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN con_1 WHEN flag = 2 THEN con_2 ELSE NULL END AS con,
    description
FROM product_table p where flag <> 0 )

select component,
array_agg(description),
array_agg(con)

from cte group by 1
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wazWZ6j8YbtPZZVodrm4xx/1)

In case you want to avoid the null values in `con` (in case flag is other than 0,1,2) and distinct values in description also then try like this

```
with cte as (
SELECT DISTINCT on (1,2) component,
    CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN con_1 WHEN flag = 2 THEN con_2 ELSE NULL END AS con,
    description
FROM product_table p where flag <> 0 )

select component,
array_agg(distinct description),
array_agg(con)

from cte where con is not null group by 1
```